# On line-height change, adjacent buttons and text below buttons move down when one button is clicked

Tags: html, css

I have a `.button` class which on the active state adds an `inset box shadow` and increases the `line-height` by 2 to give a button press effect. But the button adjacent to it and the text below it also move down which I do not want. Could you please tell me how can I achieve this effect without the anything else moving?

Note: I only want the text inside the button to move down by 2px on button press and hence I chose using the `line-height`.

```css
.button{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 36px;
  padding: 0 18px;
  background: cyan;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  line-height: 36px;
  margin: 6px;
}

.button:active, .button:focus{
  outline: none;
}

.button:active{
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 blue inset; 
  line-height: 38px;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Hello!</button>
<button class="button">Bye!</button>
<div>Hello!</div>
```

Comment: just avoid playing with line height

Comment: that doesnt help me. can you suggest an alternative way to achieve this effect then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `vertical-align: top;` to your `.button` styles.

Default value of `vertical-align` property is `base-line`. When one button is focused, because of change in its `line-height`, alignment of `.button` elements gets disturbed and as a result it push down the below content.

```css
.button{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 36px;
  padding: 0 18px;
  background: cyan;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  line-height: 36px;
  margin: 6px;
}

.button:active, .button:focus{
  outline: none;
}

.button:active{
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 blue inset; 
  line-height: 38px;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Hello!</button>
<button class="button">Bye!</button>
<div>Hello!</div>
```

Comment: @takeradi I've added explanation)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making the line height 38px and adding transparent box shadow (of the same height) when button is not active. This way in active state nothing will be moved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with a transformation:

```css
.button{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 36px;
  padding: 0 18px;
  background: cyan;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  line-height: 36px;
  margin: 6px;
}

.button:active, .button:focus{
  outline: none;
}

.button:active{
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 blue inset; 
  transform:translateY(2px);
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Hello!</button>
<button class="button">Bye!</button>
<div>Hello!</div>
```

Comment: I just want the text to move. I dont want the whole button to move